# Assign ArrayList from the data in propeties file

Tags: spring

this is my property file.

```
REDCA_IF_00001=com.sds.redca.biz.svc.RedCAIF00001SVC 
REDCA_IF_00002=com.sds.redca.biz.svc.RedCAIF00002SVC
REDCA_IF_00003=com.sds.redca.biz.svc.RedCAIF00003SVC
REDCA_IF_00004=com.sds.redca.biz.svc.RedCAIF00004SVC
```

and I want to these values into hashmap in my spring context file.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be a `HashMap` or any kind of `Map` would be fine?

Because you can define that as a `java.util.Properties` instance (Spring has great support for properties loading), which already implements `Map` (it actually extends from `Hashtable`).

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have two questions. first, and then how can i register values to spring bean? second, i can use properties in java file but I want to to this in xml file.

Comment: Do you want each of those values registered as individual beans in your context or you just need a Map structure that associates the keys to some simple type (like `String` or `Class`) values?